# Google App Engine Authentication with Google Apps domain account

Tags: android, google-app-engine, authentication

Actually we have created the backend module for our android app in Google cloud module.

We also did the validation for authenticating users in backend module(Google cloud module) following the below reference,

And also we picked the authentication option as Google Apps domain. And also we did the below configuration in console.cloud.google.com,

(Google app engine->Setting->Authentication->Google apps domain->mycompany.com)
We followed the below reference for client application(android app) to make API call,

[https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/calling-from-android].

Now we are expecting like the login success will happen only the registered Google apps domain users (Ex: user@mycompany.com). But all the google account users getting success login.

So kindly provide you advice to make the expected workflow.

Answer (score 0):

If the invocation of the service EndPoint you realize it from the web , you can use https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/ otherwise check authentication control endpoint.